# How to get selected value of nested object array using ngFor in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object as:

```
test = [
{"obj1": {"time":"8:00","array":[{name: "user1", "language": "En"},{"name": "user4", "language": "Fr"}]}}
{"obj2": {"time":"8:00","array":[{name: "user2", "language": "Fr"},{"name": "user3", "language": "Sp"}]}}
]
```

My HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let obj of test">
<div *ngFor="let item of obj.array">
<p>{{obj.time}}</p>
<p>{{item.name}}</p>
<button (click)="getDetails()">Click</button>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked, I need to get the value of the "time" and "name". I know how to get the value of time as it is only one per the object. But, I am not sure how to get the values of the nested array. I think it can be done by using "index" approach. But, I cannot make it work.

Desired Output:
When I click on the button:

```
8:00,
user1,
En
```

Comment: `let item of obj.array` is problematic as `array` is nested within a dynamic property.  In one element it is nested in `obj1` and in the next it is nested in `obj2`.  You can make it work, but it would be much cleaner if the data model was consistent.

Comment: Also a little debugging tip.  Within your markup, if you put `{{ obj | json }}` in there, when you run the page, angular will spit out the `obj` in json, so you can take a look at what you are dealing with.

Comment: Do you want to get value of all names? I didn't get the point of the question.

Comment: @JorgeMussato , When I click on the button, I should get the respective nested array object name and language and the time in the main object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can pass the iteration object to the TS as a function parameter. Example:

In your HTML you should:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of test">
  <div *ngFor="let item of obj.array">
    <p>{{obj.time}}</p>
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <button (click)="getDetails(obj, item)">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the TS you do

```
getDetails(obj, item) {
  console.log(obj.time, item.name); // The values you want here.
}
```